# WebdriverIO ERROR: Cannot find module 'tap' browserName: "chrome"

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, jasmine, webdriver-io

I have an issue running webdriverio and I can't find a way to make it work.

It was working before, I've changed a few things, reverted them but I keep having the same error.

When I run the command: `wdio wdio.jasmine.conf.js`, I can see the browser opening, but then I get this error.

```
ERROR: Cannot find module 'tap'
browserName: "chrome"
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

My package.json doesn't have much, everything is installed globally (`selenium-standalone, webdriverio@3.4.0, jasmine, wdio-jasmine-framework, chromedriver`).

Any idea what causes this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, I had to manually install `tap` and `tape` npm packages.

Those packages are used by `eslint` and `gulp-webdriver`.